# Is there any way to see android studio terminal logs who disappears out of terminal window by sliding up automatically?

Tags: android, android-studio, terminal

Sometimes i execute commands like assembleRelease and it produces so much output that real error gets out of window and I am not able see it,Is there any way so i can see all the logs , from beginning of command execution till its end?

Comment: I vaguely remember that Android Studio stores terminal output somewhere..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it,Is there any way so i can see all the logs , from beginning of command execution till its end?

No, not really, because Terminal got no idea what's going on, so there's no context it could rely on to know what output belongs to which invoked command etc.

But.... as basically every other dumb terminal in existence does, it simply keeps past messages in back buffer so you still can review older output manually. Defaut size of back buffer size for InteliJ based IDEs is 1 MiB. If buffer gets full, any new message that is added to the buffer automatically causes (some) oldest entries to be removed from the buffer to make room for new one. Luckily you can adjust buffer size to you liking/needs and make it say 10 MiB in size (or even more depending on your machine specs) so it could stuff more messages. To do that, go to `Settings -> Editor -> General -> Console` then enable `Override console cycle buffer size` and modify its value, as shown:

[image]

Note that back buffer is not persistent - quiting InteliJ/AS or terminating shell session will discard it.